# Run same code multiple times in parallel with different parameter

Tags: c#, task

This very simple example:

```
        int numLanes = 8;
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 0; i < numLanes; ++i)
        {
            var t = new Task(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Lane {i}");
            });
            tasks.Add(t);
        }
        tasks.ForEach((t) => t.Start());
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Produces:

```
Lane 8
Lane 8
Lane 8
Lane 8
Lane 8
Lane 8
Lane 8
Lane 8
```

Which is not as expected, the parameter `i` isn't passed correctly. I had thought to use `Action<int>` to wrap the code but couldn't see how I would. I do not want to write a dedicated method like `Task CreateTask(int i)` I'm interested how to do it using lambdas.

What is normal way to do this - spin up the same code a bunch of times in parallel with a different parameter value?

Comment: And yes I know, `await` etc not `WaitAll` it's just a noddy test app.

Comment: Out of interest _can_ I encapsulate this code as an Action/local lambda taking a parameter, which is then called in the loop with different parameters? `Action<T>` and `<Action>` seem incompatible... if anyone can provide an answer on that direction it'd be interesting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a captured loop variable `i`, try to add temp variable inside a loop and pass it to the `Task`

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < numLanes; ++i)
{
    var temp = i;
    var t = new Task(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Lane {temp}");
    });
    tasks.Add(t);
}
```

Further reading [How to capture a variable in C# and not to shoot yourself in the foot](https://medium.com/@unicorn_dev/how-to-capture-a-variable-in-c-and-not-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-d169aa161aa6). `foreach` loop has the same behavior before C# 5, but according to link above

> with the release of the C# 5.0 standard this behavior was changed by
>   declaring the iterator variable inside every loop iteration, not
>   before it on the compilation stage, but for all other constructions
>   similar behavior remained without any changes

So, you may use `foreach` without temp variable

Comment: I was trying to see if I could _force_ my lambda to _take_ a parameter instead of capturing `i` but could not see how to do so? But this is clearly the simple answer to my code's problem - thanks

Comment: @Mr.Boy I think, that capturing of variable is standard way, how the lambda works. Please, refer to the article, which I've mentioned above. Under the hood compiler generates a class and having a temp variable seems to be the only way to avoid capturing

Answer (score 5):

You need to capture the value inside the `for` loop otherwise all of the `Task`s are still referring to the same object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numLanes; ++i)
{
    var innerI = I; // Copy the variable here
    var t = new Task(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Lane {innerI}");
    });
    tasks.Add(t);
}
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ to create a closure for each lambda you pass to the `Task` constructor:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, numLanes - 1)
    .Select(i => new Task(() => Console.WriteLine($"Lane {i}")));
```

Comment: As I found later, the one warning here is lazy evaluation means tasks are not necessarily run when you think (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61349364/why-are-parallel-tasks-not-running)

Comment: Once you become familiar with LINQ, it becomes second nature that execution is deferred. If you need immediate execution just add a `ToList()`, which will immediately iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (without introducing additional variable inside `for` loop) is to use constructor [`Task(Action<object>, object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=netframework-4.5#System_Threading_Tasks_Task__ctor_System_Action_System_Object__System_Object_):

```
int numLanes = 8;
var tasks = new List<Task>();

for (int i = 0; i < numLanes; ++i)
{
    // Variable "i" is passed as an argument into Task constructor.
    var t = new Task(arg =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Lane {0}", arg);
    }, i);
    tasks.Add(t);
}

tasks.ForEach((t) => t.Start());
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

---

In `C# 5` and later `foreach` loop introduces a new variable on each iteration. Therefore in `C# 5` and later it is possible to use `foreach` to create tasks where each task captures its own loop variable (also no need to introduce additional variable inside loop):

```
int numLanes = 8;
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, numLanes))
{
    // A new "i" variable is introduced on each iteration.
    // Therefore each task captures its own variable.
    var t = new Task(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Lane {0}", i);
    });
    tasks.Add(t);
}

tasks.ForEach((t) => t.Start());
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```