# Why are parallel tasks not running?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have this code, it is the skeleton of larger functionality stripped down to prove the problem:

```
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
            .Select(laneNo => Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine($"Starting generator for lane {laneNo}")));

        for(int r=0; ;++r)
        {
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Wait();

            Console.WriteLine($"Iteration {r} at {DateTime.Now}");
        }
```

I never see "Starting generator" printed to Console but I do see the iteration fire every 3 seconds - something is causing those tasks not to progress (in the real code they run for a significant period but removing that doesn't affect the problem).

Why are the first bunch of Tasks not running? My theory is it's related to `Task.Delay`?

Comment: (This is quick'n'dirty code for a test-app/simulator by the way)

Comment: If you simply want to run some synchronous code in parallel, just use Parallel.ForEach and be done with it.

Comment: Where in your code are you displaying Parallel Tasks?  You for loop is just display tasks in series.  Your tasks could be terminating before you ever get to the for loop.

Comment: @jdweng they are not running at all. In the real code they do longer stuff but since they do not even print to Console, something is wrong

Comment: Also @jdweng it still is in parallel. If you run 'display tasks' in this way you'll typically see them print out-of-order.

Comment: Which Write Statement?  The first Write you have multiple Tasks each with a Console that closes when the task finishes.  The 2nd is inside a for loop that prints a message.  Task.Delay is a static method that is not linked to the tasks variable.  The for loop runs forever and just outputs a message every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ `Select` has deferred execution; it simply defines an iterator, so your `Task`s are not being generated.

You could make use of [`Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__), which will iterate and await each `Task`, generating new `Task` that completes once all the provided tasks have also completed:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
        .Select(laneNo => Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine($"Starting generator for lane {laneNo}")));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I don't know I ever would've figured this one out, I wasn't looking in that direction at all! I thought I was saving a line of code doing `Task.Run` instead of `new Task`, and then `Start`ing in a loop. I never realised these were lazily evaluated in that way :)

Answer (score 2):

Your linq-statment is never materialized. Linq-operators like Select, Where, OrderBy, etc work as building blocks that you chain together but they are not executed until you run it through a foreach or use operators which do not return enumerables, like ToArray, ToList, First, Last etc.

If you call ToList at the end you should see all of the tasks executing but if you only call First you should see only a single one because the iteration of your original Range will then terminate after first element.